# Group the rows that are having the same value in specific field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am having the following data in MySQL table.

```
+--------+----------+------+
| job_id | query_id | done |
+--------+----------+------+
|  15145 | a002     |    1 |
|  15146 | a002     |    1 |
|  15148 | a002     |    1 |
|  15150 | a002     |    1 |
|  15314 | a003     |    0 |
|  15315 | a003     |    1 |
|  15316 | a003     |    0 |
|  15317 | a003     |    0 |
|  15318 | a003     |    1 |
|  15319 | a003     |    0 |
+--------+----------+------+
```

I would like to know if it's possible to have a sql query, which can group by query_id **IF ALL 'done' fields are marked as 1**. The possible output I imagine would be:

```
+----------+------+
| query_id | done |
+----------+------+
|  a002    |  1   |
|  a003    |  0   |
+----------+------+
```

I've tried the following SQL query:

```
select job_id, query_id, done from job_table group by done having done = 1 ;
```

But no luck.  I would really appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not particullarly proud of this solution because it is not very clear, but at least it's fast and simple. If all of the items have *"done" = 1* then the sum will be equal to the count SUM = COUNT

```
SELECT query_id, SUM(done) AS doneSum, COUNT(done) AS doneCnt 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY query_id
```

And if you add a having clause you get the items that are "done".

```
HAVING doneSum = doneCnt
```

I'll let you format the solution properly, you can do a DIFERENCE to get the "not done" items or doneSum <> doneCnt.

Btw, SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/437f8/3).

Answer (score 2):

All "done" jobs :

```
SELECT * FROM job_table GROUP BY done HAVING MIN(done) = 1;
```

All "undone" jobs :

```
SELECT * FROM job_table GROUP BY done HAVING MAX(done) = 0;
```

All jobs having the same value ("done" OR "undone") :

```
SELECT * FROM job_table GROUP BY done HAVING MAX(done) = 0 OR MIN(done) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The output in your example can be obtained as:

```
SELECT query_id, min(done) as done
FROM job_table
GROUP by done
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like

```
SELECT qry_id, 1
FROM (
    SELECT qry_id, done
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY qry_id, done
) AS t
GROUP BY qry_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
UNION
SELECT qry_id, 0
FROM (
    SELECT qry_id, done
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY qry_id, done
) AS t
GROUP BY qry_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: Thank you. But both query_id show "0" rather than "1" and "0"

Answer (score -3):

I think you should be looking at this

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
```